# How to get session data and put in a dropDownList in Yii 2?

Tags: php, session, yii2

I'm new in StackOverflow and also new using the framework Yii 2, and I need to get session data and put in a create and update form using the `_form.php` from a view called **Planficacion**, but when I try to use this line of code in the form:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'rutProfesor')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::getvalue(Yii::$app->user->identity->rutProfesor,'nombreProfesor')) ?>
```

Return this error: PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException. Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

I need to get the value of *'nombreProfesor'* from a model called **Profesor**, and the relation of both **Planificacion** and **Profesor** is *'rutProfesor'* and I want to show in the dropDownList only the *'nombreProfesor'* of the actual session.

There are the codes from:

**Profesor Model** (`Profesor.php`)

```
<?php

namespace common\models;

use Yii;

class Profesor extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'profesor';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['rutProfesor'], 'required'],
            [['nombreProfesor', 'apellidoProfesor', 'escuelaProfesor'], 'string', 'max' => 45],
            [['rutProfesor', 'claveProfesor'], 'string', 'max' => 15],
            [['rol'], 'string', 'max' => 2],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'nombreProfesor' => 'Nombre Profesor',
            'apellidoProfesor' => 'Apellido Profesor',
            'escuelaProfesor' => 'Escuela',
            'rutProfesor' => 'Rut',
            'claveProfesor' => 'Clave Profesor',
            'rol' => 'Rol',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getPlanificacions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Planificacion::className(), ['rutProfesor' => 'rutProfesor']);
    }
}
```

**Planificacion Model** (`planificacion.php`)

```
<?php

namespace common\models;

use Yii;

class Planificacion extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'planificacion';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['fecha', 'fechaRevision', 'fechaPlanificacion'], 'safe'],
            [['objetivosPlanificacion', 'actividad1', 'actividad2', 'actividad3', 'actividad4', 'obsActividad1', 'obsActividad2', 'obsActividad3', 'obsActividad4', 'contenidoActividad1', 'contenidoActividad2', 'contenidoActividad3', 'contenidoActividad4'], 'string'],
            [['rutProfesor'], 'string', 'max' => 15],
            [['nombreSesion', 'recursosUtilizadosPlanificacion', 'estadoActividad1', 'estadoActividad2', 'estadoActividad3', 'estadoActividad4', 'evalActividad1', 'evalActividad2', 'evalActividad3', 'evalActividad4', 'nombreSupervisor', 'asistencia'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['estado', 'rutSupervisor'], 'string', 'max' => 30],
            [['rutProfesor'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Profesor::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['rutProfesor' => 'rutProfesor']],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'idPlanificacion' => 'Id Planificacion',
            'rutProfesor' => 'Nombre Profesor',
            'fecha' => 'Fecha',
            'nombreSesion' => 'Nombre Sesion',
            'objetivosPlanificacion' => 'Objetivos Planificacion',
            'recursosUtilizadosPlanificacion' => 'Recursos Utilizados Planificacion',
            'actividad1' => 'Actividad1',
            'actividad2' => 'Actividad2',
            'actividad3' => 'Actividad3',
            'actividad4' => 'Actividad4',
            'estadoActividad1' => 'Estado Actividad1',
            'estadoActividad2' => 'Estado Actividad2',
            'estadoActividad3' => 'Estado Actividad3',
            'estadoActividad4' => 'Estado Actividad4',
            'obsActividad1' => 'Obs Actividad1',
            'obsActividad2' => 'Obs Actividad2',
            'obsActividad3' => 'Obs Actividad3',
            'obsActividad4' => 'Obs Actividad4',
            'contenidoActividad1' => 'Contenido Actividad1',
            'contenidoActividad2' => 'Contenido Actividad2',
            'contenidoActividad3' => 'Contenido Actividad3',
            'contenidoActividad4' => 'Contenido Actividad4',
            'evalActividad1' => 'Eval Actividad1',
            'evalActividad2' => 'Eval Actividad2',
            'evalActividad3' => 'Eval Actividad3',
            'evalActividad4' => 'Eval Actividad4',
            'estado' => 'Estado',
            'fechaRevision' => 'Fecha Revision',
            'rutSupervisor' => 'Rut Supervisor',
            'fechaPlanificacion' => 'Fecha Planificacion',
            'nombreSupervisor' => 'Nombre Supervisor',
            'asistencia' => 'Asistencia',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getAsistencias()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Asistencia::className(), ['idPlanificacion' => 'idPlanificacion']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getRutProfesor0()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Profesor::className(), ['rutProfesor' => 'rutProfesor']);
    }
}
```

**User Model** (`User.php`)

```
<?php
namespace common\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\NotSupportedException;
use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\helpers\Security;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;

class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
    const STATUS_DELETED = 0;
    const STATUS_ACTIVE = 10;

    const ROLE_SUPERVISOR = 1;
    const ROL_PROFESOR = 2;

    public $authKey;

    /** @inheritdoc
    /**
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'profesor';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            TimestampBehavior::className(),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['status', 'default', 'value' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE],
            ['status', 'in', 'range' => [self::STATUS_ACTIVE, self::STATUS_DELETED]],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function findIdentity($rutProfesor)
    {
        return static::findOne(['rutProfesor' => $rutProfesor]);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException('"findIdentityByAccessToken" is not implemented.');
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by username
     *
     * @param string $username
     * @return static|null
     */
    public static function findByUsername($rutProfesor)
    {
        return static::findOne(['rutProfesor' => $rutProfesor]);
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by password reset token
     *
     * @param string $token password reset token
     * @return static|null
     */
    public static function findByPasswordResetToken($token)
    {
        if (!static::isPasswordResetTokenValid($token)) {
            return null;
        }

        return static::findOne([
            'password_reset_token' => $token,
            'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Finds out if password reset token is valid
     *
     * @param string $token password reset token
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function isPasswordResetTokenValid($token)
    {
        if (empty($token)) {
            return false;
        }

        $timestamp = (int) substr($token, strrpos($token, '_') + 1);
        $expire = Yii::$app->params['user.passwordResetTokenExpire'];
        return $timestamp + $expire >= time();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->getPrimaryKey();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getAuthKey()
    {
        return $this->authKey;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
    {
        return $this->getAuthKey() === $authKey;
    }

    /**
     * Validates password
     *
     * @param string $password password to validate
     * @return bool if password provided is valid for current user
     */
    public function validatePassword($claveProfesor)
    {
        return $this->claveProfesor === $claveProfesor;
    }

    /**
     * Generates password hash from password and sets it to the model
     *
     * @param string $password
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password_hash = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($password);
    }

    /**
     * Generates "remember me" authentication key
     */
    public function generateAuthKey()
    {
        $this->auth_key = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
    }

    /**
     * Generates new password reset token
     */
    public function generatePasswordResetToken()
    {
        $this->password_reset_token = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString() . '_' . time();
    }

    /**
     * Removes password reset token
     */
    public function removePasswordResetToken()
    {
        $this->password_reset_token = null;
    } 

    public function isUserSimple($rutProfesor)
    {
        if(static::findOne(['rutProfesor' => $rutProfesor, 'rol' => 2]))
        {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function isUserAdmin($rutProfesor)
    {
        if(static::findOne(['rutProfesor' => $rutProfesor, 'rol' => 1]))
        {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

**Planificacion Controller** (`planificacionController.php`)

```
<?php

namespace frontend\controllers;

use Yii;
use common\models\Planificacion;
use common\models\PlanificacionSearch;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;

/**
 * PlanificacionController implements the CRUD actions for Planificacion model.
 */
class PlanificacionController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['POST'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Lists all Planificacion models.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new PlanificacionSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Displays a single Planificacion model.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new Planificacion model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Planificacion();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->idPlanificacion]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Updates an existing Planificacion model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->idPlanificacion]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an existing Planificacion model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->findModel($id)->delete();

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }

    /**
     * Finds the Planificacion model based on its primary key value.
     * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return Planificacion the loaded model
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = Planificacion::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You posted a lot of code, but forgot to ask a question!

Comment: I asked about how to get session data and put in a dropDownList in Yii 2. Sorry if the question is poorly described. I just don't know how to ask a better question. Only I have that problem of get and put a certain value from session data on a dropDownList, but I don't know what to add in this question...

Comment: sorry, I overlooked that one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, why you getting the error, is because [ArrayHelper::getValue()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basearrayhelper.html#getValue()-detail) require an array as first parameter, as it's purpose is to

> Retrieves the value of an array element or object property with the
>   given key or property name.

And `Yii::$app->user->identity->rutProfesor` wouldn't yield an array, no, it would yield an single string, which is current rutProfessor in the session.

Then, on how you create the dropDownList you wanted, i suggest using an [ArrayHelper::map()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basearrayhelper.html#map()-detail) which is more straightfoward.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'rutProfesor')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(Profesor::find()->where([
 'rutProfesor' => Yii::$app->user->identity->rutProfesor
])->all(), 'rutProfesor', 'nombreProfesor'); ?>
```

I beleive that code will do you good.

Happy coding. :)